# Android app crashes when an Azure SQL query is made

Tags: java, android, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

Any help is greatly appreciated. I have created a backend for my Android App using the Microsoft Azure Mobile SDK for Android Studio. But when I try to get data from the server using a query, the app hangs and crashes. My code is as follows:

```
//The variables
private MobileServiceClient mClient;
private MobileServiceTable<Item> table;

//In onCreate method
try {
    mClient = new MobileServiceClient("https://myapp.azurewebsites.net", this);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
table = mClient.getTable("MyTable",Item.class);
try {
    final List<Item> result =  table.execute().get();//----App crashes here
} catch (MobileServiceException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What does the stacktrace say? "hangs and crashes" contains exactly zero details.

Comment: Well if this is the main thread execute a query and getting the result like that will cause a NetworkOnMainThreadException.  But you didn't post a stack trace so I'm guessing.  In general though you should never do a get() on an AsyncTask.  I wish they'd remove the call to stop people from using it.

Comment: Your probably getting as NetworkOnMainThreadException. You should never run network tasks on the main thread. Use an ASyncTask. 
You should also pop the stack trace in the question so we can see the error.

Answer (score 1):

@AnshaySaboo There are two services named `Azure Mobile Services` (old service on Azure classic portal) & `Azure Mobile Apps` (new service on Azure new portal) on Azure. According to your description, I can't recognize which service you used. However, based on the constructor [`MobileServiceClient(String appUrl, Context context)`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-android-client/blob/master/sdk/src/sdk/src/main/java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/mobileservices/MobileServiceClient.java#L245), I think you are using [Azure Mobile Apps SDK for Android](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-android-client), not [Azure Mobile Services SDK for Android](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services).

I think the issue might be caused by using Mobile Service SDK for Android when you create a Mobile App service on Azure new portal. So please check which service you used as backend and which sdk you used for Android client, and make sure the service consistency for your backend and client.

As reference, there are some resources for different services.

1. Get started with [Mobile Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-get-started/) vs [Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-android-get-started/).
2. How to use the Android client library for [Mobile Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-how-to-use-client-library) vs [Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library/).
3. Samples on GitHub: [Mobile Services](https://github.com/Azure/mobile-services-samples/tree/master/GettingStarted/Android/ZUMOAPPNAME/src/com/example/zumoappname) vs [Mobile Apps](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts/tree/master/client/android/ZUMOAPPNAME/app/src/main/java/com/example/zumoappname).